# Invalid Host Header Apache2

Tags: apache, proxy, cornerstonejs

I have configured a reverse proxy with apache so that the domain that I have configured redirects to localhost:3000 with the following configuration in the virtual hosts configuration file:

`<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName corner.at3w-connect.systems:3000 ProxyPreserveHost On ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/ </VirtualHost>`

But when I put the domain "corner.at3w-connect.systems:3000" it returns the message "Invalid Host header" and this message appears once I have started the Cornerstone example using the following command: "yarn run example examplename", within the example I point to a domain to access the Orthanc web server to view dicom images.

I have configured the virtual host file, I have tried adding new rules within the configuration file, creating a new configuration file, modifying the original configuration file...